# How to retrieve all values for a particular key in karate

Tags: karate

How to retrieve partNumbers from below response. In below response

```
  "10000061","10000062","10000063"
```

are dynamic in nature. I have to match these partNumbers with data table partnumbers.( In a response there could be more than 10 part numbers(based on input) and i have to validate them.)

```
{ "added": true, "lineItems": { "1111111": { "itemCore": { "partNumber": 
"10000061" } }, "222222": { "itemCore": { "partNumber": "10000061" } }, 
 "3333333": { "itemCore": { "partNumber": "10000063" } } } }
```

Tried below

```
def partNum= get[0] response..itemCore.partNumber[*] but getting empty array.
def partNum= get[0] response..itemCore.partNumber but getting empty value.
```

My below second approach also giving me empty value.

```
 * def keys = function(obj){ return response.lineItems.keySet() }
 * json dynamicValue= keys(response)
 * print 'dynamic value '+dynamicValue
 * def first = dynamicValue[0]
 * print response.lineItems.dynamicValue[0].itemCore.partNumber
 * print response.lineItems.first.itemCore.partNumber
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For retrieving data for a particular key, you can use deep scan operator in jsonPath,

```
* def partNumbers = karate.jsonPath(response,"$..partNumber")
```

Comment: @ Babu Sekaran : Your solution did work for me..Thank you..!

Answer (score 3):

Here's another solution, using `karate.forEach()` which can also operate on a map, not just a list:

```
  * def keys = []
  * eval karate.forEach(response.lineItems, function(k){ keys.add(k) })
  * print keys
```

Comment: Thank you for you quick response it is helping me to retrieve keys sets . But here I am trying retrieve all values of partnumbers and compare with data values coming from the data table as mentioned earlier.
{ "partNumber": "10000061" } }

Example:
|pNum|
|10000061|

Comment: @sam compare what ? which data table ? what do you mean by "compare" ? provide an example. kindly mark this answer as accepted and open a new one - please try to be more clear in your questions

Comment: @ptrthomas sorry to confuse you. Please let me know how to retrieve partnumber values from above response.

Comment: @sam the expected part numbers which you mentioned caused a wrong interpretation, I have changed the question now and updated my answer as well